# Node.js - Disabling Browser's Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, server-side

For instance, if a browser has javascript disabled does node.js still work or does it need  a fallback?

I know this might be a stupid question, but i'm trying to prove to a friend that node.js works on the server-side and doesn't rely on the client side.

Comment: Showing him the CLI rather than the browser is a good start.

Comment: So your friend thinks that Node spawns a browser under the hood to run Javascript code? A simple process list would show them the opposite is true.

Comment: Just direct your friend to the Wikipedia page. And if you want to show your friend that Node works when the browser's JavaScript is disabled, _why haven't you just shown him that_?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I think his friend thinks something different, e.g., they're conflating client and server side, regardless of the mechanism node uses to run JavaScript.

Comment: @Dave, that's indeed a possibility. In that case, something like `wget`, `curl` or even `telnet` can prove that JS code is executed without a browser running on the client.

Comment: Thanks everybody for replying so quickly, i hope i can prove him wrong, because he thinks that when you disable the javascript there's some sort of fallback

Comment: Here is another way to look at it: browsers don't support PHP at all, and yet all those PHP servers are working fine with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed by @frédéric-hamidi run a node server and then curl it:

**nodejs**

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('I don\'t need js on the browser!');
}).listen(80);
```

**shell**

```
curl http://web-07081482-2b2c-4e1b-9b1c-9ab20dccb92c.runnable.com/
```

You can show him this demo:

http://runnable.com/VM9-XCkU5E06W8gl/nodejs-so-for-node-js-and-hello-world

Answer (score 1):

**Node.js, in and of itself, will continue to work even if the browser has JavaScript disabled (or has no support for it to begin with)**. It is a server-side environment, and therefore has nothing to do with the browser. It does its work before the client even sees the page (or AJAX response, if you're doing those).

**Node.js cannot bypass the browser's JavaScript settings, but that's true for any server-side development environment**. If you make something in Node.js that depends on the client to calculate something and send it back, then *that* won't work properly if the browser has JavaScript disabled. So you do have to be careful not to lose track of what code is client-side and what is server-side, which is *slightly* more difficult when both types of code use the same language, but is still not very hard. As long as you do that, you will be fine.

**Personally, my favorite kind of demo for this sort of thing is to use `telnet`**, as @FredericHamidi mentioned. It's difficult to get more bare-bones than `telnet`, since it does almost nothing for you: there is no JavaScript, no CSS, not even HTML. There isn't even HTTP, really; it can't construct the request by itself, so you have to type it in manually (which isn't so bad if you stick to HTTP/0.9 and GET requests for your demos, but I don't recommend getting any more complex than that). To an untrained eye, it looks like you're hacking into the machine. **But Node.js will still run, even when you're running on essentially the most bare-bones client possible**.

Comment: Thank you for explaining, i guess the doubt that my friend had was that after he disabled the javascript, the pages didn't present themselves properly due to the javascript files that work on the client side and possibly rely on node.js to retrieve information to the pages.

Answer (score 0):

You've already said it. Node code is interpreted on the server hosting your application, not on the client.

You could proof that to your friend by receiving a response from a node powered server from a browser that has disabled JS.